# Divide Int to Int and return Int

Tags: haskell, int

I need a function which gets two `Int`s (`a` and `b`) and returns `A/B` as `Int`. I am sure that `A/B` will always be an integer.

Here is my solution:

```
myDiv :: Int -> Int -> Int
myDiv a b = 
      let x = fromIntegral a
          y = fromIntegral b
      in truncate (x / y)
```

But want to find more simpler solution. Something like this:

```
myDiv :: Int -> Int -> Int
myDiv a b = a / b
```

How can I divide Int to Int and get Int ?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Why not just use `quot`?

```
quot a b
```

is the integer quotient of integers a and b truncated towards zero.

Comment: Or `a \`quot\` b` for the infix lovers (wow, you can actually escape backticks insice backticks with backslash?).

Comment: Also `a \`div\` b`; if I remember correctly, `quot` truncates (like demas wanted), and `div` rounds towards zero.  So `(-3) \`quot\` 4 == 0`, and `(-3) \`div\` 4 == -1`.

Comment: +1 for `div`.  More mathematically well-behaved, `quot` is a bitch when there are negative numbers around.

Comment: This was a life-saver for me. I was wrestling with `fromIntegral (ceiling (int1 / int2))` and other things--none of which gave me back an `Int`, but this one did.

Comment: `div` rounds towards negative inifinity, not zero.

Comment: in ghci: `<interactive>:12:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Fractional (a -> a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Fractional (a -> a), Integral a) => a -> a`

Comment: @mLstudent33 I hope it's clear that you're responding to an 11 year old answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to make my own:

```hs
quot' a b
         | a<b = 0  -- base case
         | otherwise = 1 + quot' a-b b
```

Comment: Nice as an exercise, but useless in production. On large numbers it is slow (linear time) and has a high memory footprint (not tail-recursive). For negative numbers, it is either wrong (`a<0`) or never ends (`b<0`).