# Haskell error "parse error on input ‘if'"

Tags: haskell, if-statement, compiler-errors, list-comprehension

I got a question regarding Haskell, I tried to make a function to half an even number only in a list and return the final list with only the even number(s) got modified(got halved) with the rest of the element remained untouched.

But when I try to compile my code, I gave an error saying that "error: parse error on input ‘if'" and I couldn't find the solution for it.

```
halfEvens :: [ Int ] -> [ Int ]
halfEvens xs = [x|x<-xs]
                if x mod 2 == 0
                the x = x / 2
                else
                x = x
```

Comment: Sorry because my code is a bit messed up. So what should I do in order to make my function work as what I want ? Do you have any recommendation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping as much of your original code/intent as possible,

```
halfEvens xs = [x | x <- xs, x <- [   -- instead of x = ...
                 if x `mod` 2 == 0
                   then {- x = -} x `div` 2
                   else {- x = -} x ]]
```

Its type gets deduced as `halfEvens :: Integral t => [t] -> [t]`.

Funny thing about it is that we're allowed to use the same variable name there, with the `x <- [...]` construct; it just gets shadowed. But it's OK, since we're only interested in the new value anyway. That way we treat it mentally as a variable "update", although there's no updating variables in Haskell, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has multiple issues:

- `[x|x<-xs]` doesn't do anything useful. This will just evaluate to `xs`.
- If you're using `mod` as an infix operator, it needs backticks around it
- You can't reassign variables. `then x = x / 2` and `x = x` are illegal in Haskell.

The main problem though is the fact that you have an empty list comprehension (`[x|x<-xs]`), with an `if` expression just kind of floating underneath it. I believe your intent was to put the `if` inside of the comprehension. Something like:

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens xs = [if x `mod` 2 == 0 then x `quot` 2 else x | x <- xs]
```

Changes:

- I'm not trying to reassign anything. Each element will evaluate to whatever is left of the bar (`|`).
- `/` can't be used with integers. [Use `quot` or `div` for integer division.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359043/divide-int-to-int-and-return-int)

---

```
main = do
  putStrLn . show $ halfEvens [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

[1,1,3,2,5,3,7,4,9,0]
```

Your code shows some serious misunderstandings of Haskell though. I recommend sitting down with a good book and trying out all the examples. Haskell is not an easy language. Don't try to rush through it.

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to apply a function that halves even numbers, but leaves odd numbers alone.  We can write a function to perform this transform on a single `Int`, using `even` from the prelude:

```
halfEven :: Int -> Int
halfEven x | even x = x `div` 2
           | otherwise = x
```

Now we can `map` this function over a list of `Int`:

```
halfEvens :: [Int] -> [Int]
halfEvens xs = map halfEven xs
```

Or go point free:

```
halfEvens = map halfEven
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
halfEvens xs = [halfEven x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: What did the map do ? Is it importing the 'halfEven' back to the 'halfEvens' ? Or in other word assigning the value of  'halfEven' to the 'halfEvens' ?

Comment: @Wandy `map halfEven == \xs -> [halfEven x | x <- xs]`.